# Change size to the squares of the confusion matrix

Tags: python, plot, confusion-matrix, scikit-learn

I have a problem with size in the 'plot_confusion_matrix', the squares of the confusion matrix appear cut off. I would like to solve this problem.

```
svc = SVC(kernel='linear',C=1,probability=True)
svc.fit(X_train, y_train)

model_evaluate(svc, (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test))
```

[image]

Comment: This is bug in matplotlib 3.1.1 - see https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/14751